# Wordpress WP_Query Infinite Loop

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

What I want to do is get the ID's of all posts inside a custom post type. I'm using this code, however it seems to be stuck in an infinite loop.

```
$query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'rdv-events', 'posts_per_page' => -1));

while ($query->have_posts()) {
    $values = get_post_custom();
    print_r($values);
}

wp_reset_postdata();
```

People place a shortcode on the site and then I want to use this to loop through some events and then echo then out. Maybe not important, but it was worth mentioning :)

Can anyone help me out? Thanks!!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You missed

```
$query->the_post();
```

Put it first in the while loop.

Comment: Wow.  That little bit is left out of many WP_Query examples out there.